# surjective homomorphisms between cyclic groups (wrong question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

This statement does not hold.

Let $C, D$ be cyclic groups and $f_1,f_2:C\rightarrow D$ be surjective homomorphisms. Show that there exists $\xi: C\rightarrow C$ such that $f_2=f_1\circ \xi$.

My method:

Let $C=<a>$, $D=<b>$.

case 1: $ord(b)=\infty$.

Then $ord(a)=\infty$. Hence $f_i(a)= \pm b$ for $i=1,2$. Hence the automorphism $\xi $ is determined.

case 2: $ord(b)=n$.

Then if $f_1(a)=k_1 b$, $f_2(a)=k_2 b$, then $k_1b$ and $k_2b$ are both generators of $D$. Hence $(k_1,n)=(k_2,n)=1$. Hence there exists $x\in \{1,\cdots,n-1\}$ such that $x k_1=k_2$ (mod $n$). Hence $f_1(xa)=xf_1(a)=xk_1b=k_2b=f_2(a)$. Let homomorphism $\xi: C\rightarrow C$, $\xi(a)=xa$. Then $f_1\circ \xi=f_2$.

But I do not know how to prove $\xi$ is automorphism...

Comment: Hint : how do you determine such homomorphisms? For what $n$ and $m$ such epimorphisms exist?

Comment: So you require $\xi$ to be an automorphism? Then your statement is wrong in general: Consider the surjective homomorphisms $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/5 \Bbb Z$ given by $1 \mapsto 1$ and $1 \mapsto 2$. The only non-trivial automorphism of $\Bbb Z$ is $1\to -1$ but it doesn't have the desired property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $C$ and $D$ finite we can indeed require $\xi$ to be an automorphism. Let me try to describe what I think is the core of the problem:

Let $C = \Bbb Z /n \Bbb Z$ and $D = \Bbb Z /m \Bbb Z$ and let $\phi:C \rightarrow D$ be a homomorphism onto D. Then $m \mid n$ and thus we can split $\phi$ into the natural projection $\pi:C \rightarrow D$ and an automorphism $\varphi: D \rightarrow D$ such that $\phi = \varphi \circ \pi$.

Now suppose $\phi_1,\phi_2:C \rightarrow D$ are different homomorphisms. We want to show that there is an automorphism $\xi:C \rightarrow C$ such that $\phi_2 = \phi_1 \circ \xi$ are conjugated. If we consider the right-action of $Aut(C)$ on $Hom(C,D)$, then this statement is equivalent to the transitivity of the action. We may show transitivity by showing that every element of $Hom(C,D)$ is conjugated to $\pi \in Hom(C,D)$.

By splitting homomorphism in $Hom(C,D)$ into projection and automorphism $\varphi$ of $D$, the latter statement is equivalent to the following **Lemma:**

> For any $\varphi \in Aut(\Bbb Z /m \Bbb Z)$ there is a lift $\xi \in Aut(\Bbb Z /n \Bbb Z)$
>   such that the following diagram commutes:
>
> $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} \Bbb Z /n \Bbb Z @>\displaystyle
>  \exists\xi>> \Bbb Z /n \Bbb Z\\ @VV\displaystyle\pi V @VV
>  \displaystyle\pi V\\ \Bbb Z /m \Bbb Z @>>\displaystyle\varphi> \Bbb Z
>  /m \Bbb Z \end{CD}$$

Proof of the Lemma: $\pi$ induces a surjective homomorphism $$\pi:\left(\Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z \right)^\times \rightarrow \left(\Bbb Z / m \Bbb Z \right)^\times$$
 As $\varphi$ is onto, $\varphi(1)$ is a generator of $\Bbb Z /m \Bbb Z$. Hence, we can choose  $g \in \left(\Bbb Z /n \Bbb Z\right)^\times$ with $\pi(g) = \varphi(1)$. Define $\xi$ by $1 \mapsto g$. Then $\xi $ is an automorphism of $\Bbb Z /\Bbb nZ$ because $g$ is a generator, and $\varphi \circ \pi(1) = \pi \circ \xi(1)$ coincide on a generator, hence the diagram commutes.

Comment: I am confused on: Then $ξ$ is an automorphism of $Z/nZ$ because g is a generator. Why should $g$ is a generator of $C$? We only know $\pi(g)$ is a generator of $D$.

Comment: Yes, but that's what the surjection $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times \rightarrow (\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z)^\times$ is about: the additive generators of $\Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z$ are exactly the elements of $(\Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z)^\times$. As we have chosen $g \in (\Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z)^\times$, it is a generator. $1$ too is a generator, so $1 \mapsto g$ is an Automorphism.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the case involving infinite groups is clear to you.

For $C$, $D$ cyclic, let $D=Z/m$. Then the surjectivity of $f_1$, $f_2$ implies that $C=Z/um$ for some integer $u$. Suppose that $f_{1}(1)=a$, $f_{2}(1)=b$, then by surjectivity $a,b$ are relatively prime to $m$. Let $k=a^{-1}b\mod m$ be an integer($b^{-1}$ just means the residue class which is the inverse of the class containing $b$), then $1 \rightarrow k$ defines an automorphism ξ on $C$ satisfying the requirement.

Comment: If D is infinite and C is finite, everything in sight is trivial.If $C$ is infinite and $D$ is finite, then the proof is exactly the same as in the finite case. If both are infinite, then there are only two surjective homomorphisms between them and both of them are isomorphisms.

Comment: In the finite setting, we have to require $a^{-1}b$ to be coprime to $n$ to get an automorphism of $C = \Bbb Z /n\Bbb Z$. This is not completely trivial, as we have to represent $a$ by an integer that is coprime to $n$.

Comment: OK, my bad. By "automorphism" I tried to mean just a homomorphism from $C$ to itself, not necessarily an isomorphism. Of course we cannot require ξ to be an isomorphism.